# What is the best rules for a App published on Play Store when using Firestore Database?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

i'll publish my app on Google Play Store but in test phases (Alpha Version), i was using this rules:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    // This rule allows anyone on the internet to view, edit, and delete
    // all data in your Firestore database. It is useful for getting
    // started, but it is configured to expire after 30 days because it
    // leaves your app open to attackers. At that time, all client
    // requests to your Firestore database will be denied.
    //
    // Make sure to write security rules for your app before that time, or else
    // your app will lose access to your Firestore database
    match /{document=**} {
     // allow read, write: if request.time < timestamp.date(2020, 3, 25);
     allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
  }
}
```

But, when the app must be published to public i can't know the best path or the best rules that my app must have.

My app have a login screen and after login screen each user have your respectives documents and collections in your document generated from sign up.

I can't got think on a form to protect my app of invasors.

Comment: There is no general "best rules" configuration.  Without knowing anything about the data in your database and what you want users to be able to do with that, we can't help.  You'll need to take some time to learn how to rules language works, and how to use that to specify who can perform which operations to which documents.  Start with the documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started

Comment: In addition to the link Doug shared, the Firestore documentation contains an example of securing access to data that is "owned" by the users of your app: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#authentication